# MS-ACCESS-2007 Visualize result of research in a table on a Form

Tags: forms, find, ms-access-2007

I've created a very small Database in MS ACCESS 2007 with one table, one Query, one form and one report.

The form contains the textboxes where the data of all the elements of one record appear.

Then there are some action buttons like "add record" or "forward", "backwards" "go to last record" etc.

There is also the search button and everything works fine.

But now there is a request that all records matching a research should be shown in a kind of table that is placed on the form itself.

Someone has got an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Update: Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a split form resolves the problem.